# R change name of dataset with stored string

Tags: r

I'm creating lots of datasets with a loop and I need to make sure that all these different datasets are properly named and stored in the workspace. My question is the following. Let's say I have a dataset (here airquality), I want to create 4 datasets and store them in the workspace

Split dataset

```
airquality$N<-letters[airquality$Month]
head(airquality)
AllDatasets<-split(airquality,airquality$N)
names(AllDatasets)
```

Now I want to extract each dataset with a loop, for example

```
#Conceptual loop
for (i in (1:names(AllDatasets))){
#Create  dataset  AllDatasets[i] and name it    names(AllDatasets)[i]
  }
```

so that after the loop I can work with each dataset (e, f, g, h, i) separately ( I don't want to apply the same function to all datasets, I want to store each single one independently in my workspace). I suppose the question doesn't just apply to loops, it's about how to rename a dataset (not its columns) with a name stored in a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `list2env()`.

```
list2env(AllDatasets, .GlobalEnv)
```

Now `e`, `f`, `g`, `h` and `i` are available in your workspace (global environment in this case, you can specify a different environment in the second argument if you like).

---

To assign a name from a string you can use `assign()`. E.g. in response to Marco's comment below:

```
D <- data.frame(rnorm(1:10), rnorm(1:2))
Name <- 'ThatOne'
assign(Name, D)
```

Or directly with a string:

```
assign('ThatOne', D)
```

Comment: MadScone, thank you very much for your quick reply. Yours is obviously the accepted answer. I would still like to know how I would  change the name of a dataset automatically (see last paragraph above):   e.g. D<-data.frame(rnorm(1:10),rnorm(1:2));
Name<-"ThatOne"; How do I create a data.frame called ThatOne which is the same as D, without directly allocating it (i.e. ThatOne<-D)?